# Elegant way to generate a random value regarding percentage?

Tags: java, algorithm, random, percentage

I have N values (integer). I'd like to know what is the most elegant way to randomly pick one of those values regarding a percentage. For example, for a 3 values example:

- Value 1 has 30% chance to get picked
- Value 2 has 12% chance to get picked
- Value 3 has 45% chance to get picked

I need this for a program i'm developing with Java but a pseudo code algorithm or a code in any other language would be ok.

Comment: `pick one of those values regarding a percentage` - didn't understand this sentence..

Comment: 30 + 12 + 45 equals 87.  What about the other 13?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One way of doing this without calculating values to use is

```
double d = Math.random() * 100;
if ((d -= 30) < 0) return 1;
if ((d -= 12) < 0) return 2;
if ((d -= 45) < 0) return 3;
return 4;
```

Answer (score 8):

Proposed algorithm:

- generate a random number (`n`) between `0` and `1` (assuming your random generator is well distributed)
- if `n < 0.30` return value `1`
- if `n < 0.42` return value `2`
- else if `n < 0.87` return value `3`
- else say Hello (your numbers don't add up to 100%)

Comment: Not `else` but `else if`, because `30 + 12 + 45 < 100`.

Comment: use `new Random().nextInt(87)` an add 1 at the result (or decrease by one step of if) - to improve if selection use 45, 30, 12 order

Comment: @assylias maybe you wanted to write if n < 0.30 ELSE if n < 0.42...?

Comment: @nathan - I think we can assume that anyone reading this is smart enough to figure that out for themselves.

Comment: @StephenC seriously? even in english "if" and "else if" means two different things. I'm just asking if the second "if" should not be "else if"

Comment: @nathan The question being tagged java, it seems fairly intuitive that `return value 1` will exit the whole if/else if block.