# Selecting a value based on percentages

Tags: java, math, random, percentage

I need to select a value based on a percentage chance of that value being selected.  For example:

- 10% of the time increment value a
- 20% of the time increment value b
- 30% of the time increment value c
- 40% of the time increment value d

The percentages will always add up to exactly 100%

I have encountered several solutions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12672765/elegant-way-to-generate-a-random-value-regarding-percentage), but have determined that they cannot possibly be correct.  Here is a sample program built using the solution mentioned:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {

    private static Random r = new Random();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int iterations = 1000000;
        System.out.println("Testing percentage based random, " + iterations + " iterations");
        int onePercent = 0;
        int sixPercent = 0;
        int sevenPercent = 0;
        int thirtySixPercent = 0;
        int fiftyPercent = 0;
        // Those values add up to 100% overall
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
            int random = r.nextInt(100);
            if (random < 1) {
                onePercent++;
                continue;
            }
            if (random < 6) {
                sixPercent++;
                continue;
            }
            if (random < 7) {
                sevenPercent++;
                continue;
            }
            if (random < 36) {
                thirtySixPercent++;
                continue;
            }
            if (random < 50) {
                fiftyPercent++;
                continue;
            }
            // That can't be right because if random > 50 then nothing at all happens
        }
        System.out.println("One percent happened about " + (onePercent / Float.valueOf(iterations)) * 100 + "% of the time");
        System.out.println("Six percent happened about " + (sixPercent / Float.valueOf(iterations)) * 100 + "% of the time");
        System.out.println("Seven percent happened about " + (sevenPercent / Float.valueOf(iterations)) * 100 + "% of the time");
        System.out.println("Thirty six percent happened about " + (thirtySixPercent / Float.valueOf(iterations)) * 100 + "% of the time");
        System.out.println("Fifty percent happened about " + (fiftyPercent / Float.valueOf(iterations)) * 100 + "% of the time");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Testing percentage based random, 1000000 iterations
One percent happened about 0.99649996% of the time
Six percent happened about 4.9925% of the time
Seven percent happened about 1.0029999% of the time
Thirty six percent happened about 29.001299% of the time
Fifty percent happened about 14.0191% of the time
```

Expected output:

```
Testing percentage based random, 1000000 iterations
One percent happened about 0.99649996% of the time
Six percent happened about 6.9925% of the time
Seven percent happened about 7.0029999% of the time
Thirty six percent happened about 36.001299% of the time
Fifty percent happened about 50.0191% of the time
```

I believe I need to use some sort of algorithm to convert the percentages into a scale from 0 to 99 so that the random number generator can select a value accurately.  I cannot think of how to do that, though.

Comment: Use `else if` instead of regular `if`

Comment: Same result since I used continue after the increment, also the percentages are still wrong

Comment: You are getting the results you should expect. You are not getting 50% simply because you are testing for values between 36 and 50. Which is 14 % probability. So this makes sense. What you should do is instead of testing values bellow 50, you should test values bellow 36 + 50. Of course this works for all your cases, not just this one

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Figured it out.  You need to keep track of the percentage tested so far and add it to the current test.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {

    private static Random r = new Random();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int iterations = 1000000;
        System.out.println("Testing percentage based random, " + iterations + " iterations");
        int onePercent = 0;
        int sixPercent = 0;
        int sevenPercent = 0;
        int thirtySixPercent = 0;
        int fiftyPercent = 0;
        // Those values add up to 100% overall
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
            int random = r.nextInt(100);
            int totalPercent = 0;
            if (random < totalPercent + 1) {
                onePercent++;
                continue;
            }
            totalPercent += 1;
            if (random < totalPercent + 6) {
                sixPercent++;
                continue;
            }
            totalPercent += 6;
            if (random < totalPercent + 7) {
                sevenPercent++;
                continue;
            }
            totalPercent += 7;
            if (random < totalPercent + 36) {
                thirtySixPercent++;
                continue;
            }
            totalPercent += 36;
            if (random < totalPercent + 50) {
                fiftyPercent++;
                continue;
            }
            totalPercent += 50;
            // That can't be right because if random > 50 then nothing at all happens
        }
        System.out.println("One percent happened about " + (onePercent / Float.valueOf(iterations)) * 100 + "% of the time");
        System.out.println("Six percent happened about " + (sixPercent / Float.valueOf(iterations)) * 100 + "% of the time");
        System.out.println("Seven percent happened about " + (sevenPercent / Float.valueOf(iterations)) * 100 + "% of the time");
        System.out.println("Thirty six percent happened about " + (thirtySixPercent / Float.valueOf(iterations)) * 100 + "% of the time");
        System.out.println("Fifty percent happened about " + (fiftyPercent / Float.valueOf(iterations)) * 100 + "% of the time");
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't over complicate it, you simply need to delete the continue; statement

Comment: That almost works, except I need there to be exactly one result per iteration.  By removing the continue statements the sum of the percent variables could be more or less than the total number of iterations.  I guess I should have specified that in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your results are correct :

> Fifty percent happened about 14.0191% of the time

**50 - 36 = 14**

> Thirty six percent happened about 29.001299% of the time

**36 - 7 = 29**

> Seven percent happened about 1.0029999% of the time

**7 - 6 = 1**

....

Delete all 'continue' statements if you want them to sum up.

Comment: So is there something I can do to the percentage values (I don't know them at compile time) so that I get the expected result (7 percent happening about 7 percent of the time)?

Comment: If you don't know them at compile time what the rule ? Each %, each 5% ?